# Smaller sized disks getting full when using hadoop on machines with multiple drives of different sizes

Tags: hadoop, emr, amazon-emr, diskspace

So I was using emr-5.4.0 on m3.xlarge machines with 250 gb EBS added on top.

With this configuration m3.xlarge with 250 gb ebs, drives are mounted as follows:

> /mnt/ : 40 gb ssd drive
>
> /mnt1/ : 40 gb ssd drive
>
> /mnt2/ : 250 gb ebs

I checked the following hadoop configs and they were as follows.

> yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs : /mnt/yarn,/mnt1/yarn,/mnt2/yarn
>
> mapreduce.cluster.local.dir : /mnt/mapred,/mnt1/mapred,/mnt2/mapred
>
> hadoop.tmp.dir : /mnt/var/lib/hadoop/tmp

But when I ran my workload, the /mnt/ and /mnt1/ drives (the SSD drives that comes with m3 machines) started getting full and the nodes got unhealthy.

Yarn provided the following messages for unhealthy nodes.

> 2/3 local-dirs are bad: /mnt/yarn,/mnt1/yarn; 1/1 log-dirs are bad:
>   /var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers
>
> 1/3 local-dirs are bad: /mnt/yarn; 1/1 log-dirs are bad:
>   /var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers

The problem was that hadoop wasn't using the attached 250gb drive for intermediate outputs or NonDFS usages.

I didn't face this problem when I used m4.2xlarge machines with 250 gb ebs. m4.* machines don't come with dedicated space as m3.* machines do (i.e. 2x40 gb ssds).

So my questions is hadoop properly able to use the available disk space when multiple drives are provided?

Answer (score 0):

As the logs suggest, the YARN CONTAINER logs probably was filling up. EMR currently does not use all disks for yarn logs. It only uses /mnt/ disk. It will be apparent if you look at the config file.

```
/etc/hadoop/conf.empty/yarn-site.xml

  <property>
    <description>Where to store container logs.</description>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs</name>
    <value>/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers</value>
  </property>
```

Here, `/var/log` is symlinked to `/mnt/var/log` .

If its that log directory, then you might need to set that property on yarn-site.xml, just like yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs (with comma separated directories of different mounts )  for the logs to distribute among all disks and not just among instance stores that come with instances.

If its not log files, then you might need to verify top directories which are using most disk and change appropriate property on .xml files and restart appropriate daemons if needed.

Comment: If you read my question, I have mentioned that I don't the face the problem when I use m4.2xlarge machine with 250 gb ebs attached. The problem appears when the machine has drives of smaller sizes.